# Integrate map applications with a react-native application

Tags: react-native, google-maps

I'm trying to implement a react-native feature similar to WhatsApp that shares a location on google maps and I can share that location with the map apps installed on the device. I would like to know if there is a way to open the native sharing mode containing only related applications.

[image: example ios]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linking function provided by react native to open many apps, besites, etc

Example

```
const latitude = "40.7127753";
const longitude = "-74.0059728";
const label = "New York, NY, USA";

const url = Platform.select({
  ios: "maps:" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?q=" + label,
  android: "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?q=" + label
});
Linking.openURL(url);
```

Comment: That way it gives me the possibility to open all available applications for maps?